# How to return QWidget that currently has focus

Tags: c++, qt, focus, qwidget

Is there a simple way to find which `QWidget` currently has focus in Qt?

Comment: `QApplication::focusWidget()` ?

Comment: Ahh I thought there was something easy like that. I just wasn't sure what it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [QApplication::focusWidget()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qapplication.html#focusWidget).